# Ссылка на классы из другого проекта

Tags: java, eclipse

Доброго времени суток.
Сложилась такая ситуация. Есть ряд классов в проекте, необходимо эти классы повторно использовать в других проектах. Проблема в том, что не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы эти классы добавить в другие проекты в виде ссылок (если возможно?!), чтобы при изменении этих классов, в других проектах эти классы тоже менялись. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать или, может, есть нехитрый способ организовать этот доступ в несколько кликов? %)

Comment: Если используете `git`, то смотрите в сторону `git submodules`. Для `hg` тоже есть аналоги. В случае использования `ant`/`maven`/`sbt`/`gradle`/etc — вынесите общий код в отдельный артефакт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.
Возможно, вам надо те классы, которые вы хотите использовать в других проектах, вынести в отдельный проект. Затем собрать его в jar и подключать как зависимость во все проекты, где это необходимо.
Если в эклипсе, то предположим, что проект А - это проект с общими классами, а проект Б - это тот проект, которому нужны эти общие классы. То, открываем проект А и Б в одном воркспейсе (workspace), затем идем в настройки проекта Б (alt+enter на проекте) -> идем в Java Build Path и добовляем во вкладочку projects проект A. Затем в том же окне идем на последнюю вкладку (не помню, как она называется) поставить галочку на проекте А, для того чтобы он попадал в сборку, если вы собираете проект в war или ear. Примерно так.
Надеюсь, это поможет.

Comment: Благодарю, уже так и сделал. Мне просто хотелось обойтись без jar'а. То есть получается, если делаю изменения, то надо jar пересобрать, и так каждый раз. )))